# How to loop 4 column in one row in bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to show 4 columns in one row in a loop but I am not able to achieve it.

I want to achieve this when I click the modal in bootstrap 4:
[I want to achieve this when I click the modal in bootstrap 4:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyWkW.png)

I am doing this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++):?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label  for="size<?=$i;?>">Size:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="size<?=$i;?>" id="size<?=$i;?>" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="qty<?=$i;?>">Quantity:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="number"  name="qty<?=$i;?>" id="qty<?=$i;?>" value="" min="0">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I AM GETTING THIS RESULT:
[I AM GETTING THIS RESULT:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlXmY.png)

I want if I have 12 size and quantity, it will show 6-6 in a row in modal-lg in bootstrap 4.

```
Size 1  Qty 1         Size 2  Qty 1
Size 3  Qty 1         Size 4  Qty 1
Size 5  Qty 1         Size 6  Qty 1
Size 7  Qty 1         Size 8  Qty 1
Size 9  Qty 1         Size 10 Qty 1
Size 11 Qty 1         Size 12 Qty 1
```

How do I manage the looping? Any Suggestions would be helpful. Thank you...

Comment: use  `col-md-3 ` to get four columns in a row.

Comment: I have used it but not getting the result what I want.

Comment: When I do col-md-3 I got size 1 Qty 1 in a line,  12 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will help you.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <?php for($i=0; $i<=11; $i++):?>
            <?php if($i%2 == 0) : ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="size<?=$i;?>">Size:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="size<?=$i;?>" id="size<?=$i;?>" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="qty<?=$i;?>">Quantity:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="qty<?=$i;?>" id="qty<?=$i;?>" value="" min="0">
                    </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="size<?=$i;?>">Size:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="size<?=$i;?>" id="size<?=$i;?>" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="qty<?=$i;?>">Quantity:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="qty<?=$i;?>" id="qty<?=$i;?>" value="" min="0">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope using this code your problem will be solved. Happy Code :).

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable outside of the for loop that holds the number/count of the $i array.

```
<?php $count = count($i);?>
```

Replace the "col-md-6" with this.

```
<?php echo ($count === 12) ? 'col-md-6': 'col-md-3'; ?>
```

Here's what you should have. Also take out the opening  at the top and bottom of your code.

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="container-fluid">
<?php $count = count($i);?>
<?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++):?>
<?php echo $count;?>

<div class="row">

<div class="form-group <?php echo (count($i) === 12) ? 'col-md-6': 'col-md-3'; ?>">
<label  for="size<?=$i;?>">Size:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text"  name="size<?=$i;?>" id="size<?=$i;?>" value="">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group <?php echo (count($i) === 12) ? 'col-md-6': 'col-md-3'; ?>">
 <label for="qty<?=$i;?>">Quantity:</label>
 <input class="form-control" type="number"  name="qty<?=$i;?>" id="qty<?=$i;?>" value="" min="0">
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endfor; ?>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: <div class="form-group <?php echo (count($i) === 12) ? 'col-md-6': 'col-md-3'; ?>">
                   <label  for="size<?=$i;?>">Size:</label>
                   <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="size<?=$i;?>" id="size<?=$i;?>" value="">
                 </div>

Comment: <div class="form-group <?php echo (count($i) === 12) ? 'col-md-6': 'col-md-3'; ?>">
                   <label for="qty<?=$i;?>">Quantity:</label>
                   <input class="form-control" type="number"  name="qty<?=$i;?>" id="qty<?=$i;?>" value="" min="0">
                 </div>
                </div>

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you are looping the row as well instead of just the columns. Also you want 2 columns so basically you have to loop in php to half of however many inputs you have and the rest in the other column. So both cols:

```
<?php for(i=1; i<6; i++):?><div class="col-md-6">First columns of inputs here</div><?php endfor; ?>
<?php for(i=1; i<6; i++):?><div class="col-md-6">First columns of inputs here</div><?php endfor; ?>
```

Loop on each of these within the row, and you should get the desired result of showing 2 columns of input loops side by side. Also keep in mind when you are looping to assign them unique id's, but most importantly do client-server side validation before inserting into DB.